# networkx calculating numeric assortativity requires int?

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to use networkx to calculate numeric assortativity based on a numeric attribute that I set to nodes. My node attributes are floats.  When I call the assortativity function:

```
assort = nx.numeric_assortativity_coefficient(G,'float_attr')
```

I got the following errors.

```
File "/some dir.../networkx/algorithms/assortativity/correlation.py", line 229, in numeric_assortativity_coefficient
a = numeric_mixing_matrix(G,attribute,nodes)
File "/some dir.../networkx/algorithms/assortativity/mixing.py", line 193, in numeric_mixing_matrix
mapping=dict(zip(range(m+1),range(m+1)))
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

I checked the [documentation page](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.assortativity.numeric_assortativity_coefficient.html#networkx.algorithms.assortativity.numeric_assortativity_coefficient) of networkx assortativity algorithm and it did not say the numeric attributes have to be int. Anyone knows if that's required?

BTW, I used the same network and a gender attribute (set to 0 and 1) to calculate both the attribute and the numeric assortativity. I had no problem with that. So it seems that the problem is with the int/float type of the node attribute.

Comment: m is somehow a float which you cannot use in range, you can try casting to int.

Comment: the m is a variable in the networkx package, not in my code. I am not sure what the m represents, and I am afraid of making changes to it as it might introduce other problems.

Comment: Ah ok, yes looking at the source there is no stipulation on type, m is the max of the dict keys returned from  `attribute_mixing_dict`. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the best way is to convert my float attribute variable into int. although that means losing some fine grained information.

Comment: You might be as well to create an issue https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues

Comment: converting the float attribute to int solves the problem. Thanks! Never submitted an issue before, guess I can give it a try. :P

Comment: I agree that this is a bug (@PadraicCunningham - want to give that as an answer?).  Looking at the code, it looks like it was written for degree assortativity originally, and then modified for arbitrary values.

Comment: @sophiadw  make sure you change all your floats to ints (maybe multiply by 10 or 100 first, though that may make performance slow?).  I suspect just making the max be an int would lead to a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved by converting the float variable into int using the following method

```
int(round(float_attr*1000, 0))
```

submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1981) and got a confirmatory answer that it only deals with discrete int values.

Peformance-wise, since my network is not huge (200+ nodes), it still takes <1 min to do the calculation.

Comment: That was a fast turn around, you can also accept your own answer.